# react-router-dom not loading the fourth element in app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

When I try to run the following code, only the header element shows on the main page or only the home element, but not together.

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header'
import Home from './Home'
import Checkout from "./Checkout"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route }
from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
    <div className='app'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/checkout" element={<Header />}/>
        <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />}/>
        
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<Header />}/>
      </Routes>
      
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is how routes in react work. Home or Header component will only show because they are the first route matches for each path. For routing with multiple components, you will need nested routes.
Take a look at this example https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for `Header` to be always shown, just take it out of `Router` component. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wfcp6m?file=App.tsx)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

function Header() {
  return <h1>Header</h1>;
}

function Checkout() {
  return <h1>Checkout</h1>;
}

function Home() {
  return <h1>Home</h1>;
}
```